# How can I Iterate through an Object and Display it as a key value pair in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, api, angular-forms

I am trying to to loop through an Object in Angular with NgFor.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getConveyors()
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.conveyors = response;
      this.conveyorsArray = Object.keys(this.conveyors.data.conveyor);
  });
```

The html looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of conveyorsArray | keyvalue">
  Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```

The data I get from api looks like the picture below.

My output:

```
Key: 0 and Value: 0
Key: 1 and Value: 1
Key: 2 and Value: 2
Key: 3 and Value: 3
Key: 4 and Value: 4
```

I want to display all conveyors.

[image: apiresp]

Comment: "I want to display all the data with angular forms" - its quite unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I want to display all conveyors

Comment: But my output is not what expected. I expected to get key of my array with it's value instead I see Key: 0 Value: 0 and so on.

Comment: Can you please paste the json response and the object that you are trying to loop through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use object.keys in your component so it should be

```
this.conveyorsArray = this.conveyors.data.conveyor;
```

instead of

```
this.conveyorsArray = Object.keys(this.conveyors.data.conveyor);
```

Then on UI loop through your array first and then use keyvalue pipe on the object instead of array

```
<div *ngFor="let arrayitem of conveyorsArray">
  <div *ngFor="let item of arrayitem | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
  </div>
</div>
```